# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null(anonymous function) @ function.js:16

Tags: javascript

I keep geting the error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null(anonymous function) @ function.js:16

Why? Am I doing sonething wrong?

```
  //sets the index varriable to 1
    var indx = 0;
    var sFirstName = [];
    var sLastName = [];
    var sNumber = [];
    var sPoints = [];
    var sFirstName = [];

     //sets text from input to var x from "usernameStudent       
        var v = document.getElementById("indx").value;
        var w = document.getElementById("sFirstName").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("sLastName").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("sNumber").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("sPoints").value;
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle that reproduces the error? I feel like more context is needed.

Comment: How about you tell us what line 16 is? Or better yet, full code or a fiddle? Although the answer is going to be "because "XXXX" is not a valid id" or "because XXXX element has no value propery"

Comment: I am 99.9999% sure that you are trying to read the value of an element before the element is rendered to the page. Other `.0001%` is you typed the id wrong or have the same id more than once.

Comment: i think element of which value you wana access is not available in the dom

Comment: Make sure you either wrap this in an onload event handler or include your JS as the last thing on the page (I.e. Don't put it in the head)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RandomRainbow7/jguebbt8/